# Adding path and linking libraries

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I am trying to complete the installation for some software. According to which I have to add path. I am not getting it how to do that. Please guide me how to do the following steps.

Add the path to Rpa/Tk headers:

```
-I/usr/include/rpatk
```

To link to the Rpa/Tk libraries on Linux add the following link options:

```
-lrpa -lrvm -lrex -lrlib -lm
```

RVM library uses some math functions from the system math library, that is why you must include '-lm' to include the math library to your project in addition to the Rpa/Tk built libraries:

librpa librex librvm librlib

http://www.rpasearch.com/rpatk/doc/doxygen/rpadoc/html/rpatk_build.html

Answer (score 0):

this will be within your configure script -- you will need to hack this and add the paths to where gcc/cc gets called

give the link to the actual tar.gz

looking at the example code: http://www.rpasearch.com/rpatk/doc/doxygen/rpadoc/html/js-tokenizer_8c-example.html

gcc -I/usr/include/rpatk -o js-tokenizer js-tokenizer.c -lrex -lrlib

so in short :

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=**/usr/include/rpatk**:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/lib

then running the configure may fix the issue

where the bit in bold would the path to the includes for this project

Comment: ye the actual download git link is not done too well  - does not seem to be working